# How to make a negative testing in magento 2 for paypal?

Tags: magento2, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to handle error payment denied from Paypal after doCapture method.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sandbox/nt-classic/#test-api-error-handling-routines

You can force two types of API errors: those related to the transaction amount, and those not related to the amount.

To trigger an error condition on an amount-related field, specify a error code value as a number with two digits to the right of the decimal point. For example, specify a value of 107.55 to trigger the 10755 error.
To trigger errors on fields that are not amount related, specify the error code in whole. For example, use a value of 10539 to trigger a "payment declined" error.

How to set the amount to trigger error ‘payment declined’ in magento 2

Any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried so far? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sandbox/nt-classic/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [Negative testing for PayPal's classic APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sandbox/nt-classic/)